# Best way to find a folder in the test directory for pytest

Tags: python, pytest

I have a folder structure as below for my pytest files

```
tests/my_test1.py
tests/input/data.txt
tests/bench/bench.csv
```

The test `my_test1.py` would have to read the file `tests/input/data.txt`. The challenge is to find the location of the file.

The tests can be invoked in Mutiple ways as mentioned here https://docs.pytest.org/en/6.2.x/usage.html. The current working directory may be different based on the invocation. so the way to open a file the input folder  `data_f = open ("./input/data.txt")` would be incorrect.

What would be the correct path to access the file? I tried to infer the path from os.getenv('PYTEST_CURRENT_TEST'). However this always give the value of the path as 'tests/' no matter from where the test is invoked.

Comment: You can use `__file__` in `my_test1.py` to get the (relative) path to `data.txt` from `my_test1.py`: `os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'input', 'data.txt')`.

Comment: To extend on the answer of @9769953: You could even write a small helper  method and import that, somthing along the lines of `def get_resource_path(name: str)` where you can just fetch resources needed. I would organize the resources in a resources folder for that matter too.

Comment: the solution would work as long as the above code is in the test itself. Hoever I have a library  where all the common code resides ( eg get_resource_path ) , and I'd need to call this function from the library. In this case the __file__ returns the path of the library and not the test file

Answer (score 3):

You could create a **fixture** in the root of the tests folder (*tests/conftest.py*) to help you read any file relative to the tests folder:

```py
from pathlib import Path
import pytest

@pytest.fixture()
def get_file():
    def _(file_path: str):
        return (Path(__file__).parent / file_path).read_text()

    return _
```

In any test you could then use the fixture to read the file for you:

```py
def test_a(get_file):
    content = get_file('input/data.txt')
    ...
```

In this example the **fixture returns a function** that would read the content of any file within *tests/* directory, but there are multiple other options:

- The fixture can return a `Path` object instead of the content.
- If you would always use the same file, it can return file object/content directly so within your test function you wouldn't need to call it.

Comment: This solution works if the conftest.py exists in the same folder as the my_test1.py or the fixures are defined in my_test1.py itself. However in my case all the fixures are defined in a common library and this library (mytestlib) is imported with a ```pytest_plugins = ["mytestlib.my_conftest"]``` code . When I keep the fixures you had mentioned in the my_conftest file, the get_file() function returns the path of the mytestlib library and not the path of the test.

Comment: I see. That's a rather important information that you forgot to mention in your question.

Comment: yes, I overlooked this aspect and realized that this is a problem when codding with the solution @tmt you had mentioned. I'm further exploring the option to use the build in fixture ```pytestconfig.getoption("file_or_dir")``` and see if the path of the executing test can be obtained.